# JTable Header contains Image and on top of that image I want to place 3 buttons in a single header

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable

JTable Header contains Image and on top of that image I want to place 3 buttons in a single header. My requirement is to Create a "Play List" table in which user can add their favourite songs.

So in the header I want to put a "Play List" title and "+" button to insert new playlists and "Export" and "Import" buttons.

How I can do that? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not sure which you want, the title says you want an image but you say you want a "Play List" title, would that be text?  If it's text then you can find a suitable layout [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 3):

I doubt<sup>(1)</sup> this use-case actually calls for cramming extra components into a `JTable` header.  E.G. Take the UI of DukeBox.

[image: DukeBox]

We can see the play list on the left (a `JTable`) with a Filter text field and Random check-box above it, and the Enqueue & History buttons below.

This was created with a nested layout.  The 'outer layout' is `BorderLayout`, that panel has the table in the `CENTER`, and nested panels in the `NORTH` & `SOUTH`.  The `NORTH` panel has another `BorderLayout`, while the `SOUTH` uses a `GridLayout`.

If using a nested layout does not give you some ideas, I suggest you post a drawing or better, ASCII art, of the UI as it should appear at the smallest size, as well as a representation of it when it is resized (where is the extra width/height assigned?).

**1)**  I have that suspicion every time I hear words to the effect *"Wouldn't it be great if we had a component that..?"*. Of course, there are some classic counter-examples where the standard widget tool-kit seems lacking (e.g. a date picker or switch list), but these are common components to which a name can be put. If the person asking cannot put a 'catchy name' to the custom component, there is a good chance they are over (or under) thinking the matter.

Comment: for UFO related connection +1

Comment: @mKorbel I set that up because it is a pumping trance/techno. track (good to listen to as I drafted the post) with great album cover art.  But the UFO connection is cool as well.  ;)